# Почему не работает ввод string

Tags: java, строки

Доброго времени суток всем. Я новичок в java. Хотелось спросить, почему в данной программе при вводе в n "january" а в d "23" будет выводится "error" а не "Vodolei"? и как это исправить, чтобы программа работала?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String n;
        int d;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter the month of your birthday");
            n = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter the day of your birthday");
            d = scan.nextInt();
        if ((n == "january" && 22<=d && d<=31) || (n =="february" && 1<=d && d<=21)) {
            System.out.println("Vodolei");

         } else {
            System.out.println("error");   
    }      
}
```

Comment: Да, вам стоит сравнивать строки через equal. И добавить **}** после **System.out.println("error");**

Comment: n == "january"/n =="february" - не правильно. n.equals("january")/n.equals("february") - правильно